# Multilevel analysis - interpretation not significant at level 1

Tags: lme4-nlme, interpretation, multilevel-analysis, fixed-effects-model

I'm doing a multilevel analysis for the first time for my master thesis.

The goal of my study was to create behaviour change through an intervention. Participants are measured for behaviour at 3 time points. Participants in the study were also assessed in terms of their personality traits. There are three different outcomes, but I intend to use the same modeling approach for each outcome.

There is no problem with two of the outcome variables but in my third model, time is not a significant predictor and model comparisons (Log Likelihood, AIC and BIC) indicate, that the model without the predictor is the better model.

My R Code for the predicted Model:

```
lmer(Behaviour3 ~ poly(occasion_cs,2)*group+(1+occasion_cs| subject) + 
  sex+age_cs+FFImeanN_cs+FFImeanE_cs+FFImeanO_cs+FFImeanC_cs+FFImeanA_cs, 
  data = data, REML = FALSE, control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")).
```

I started with a null model and then I entered the level 1 variable:

```
lmer(Behaviour3~ poly(occasion_cs,2)+(1| subject), data = data, 
  REML = FALSE,control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")).
```

After this I wanted to move on with the level 2 variables, but now I'm not sure if this would be right.

How should I proceed?

Should I stop the analysis at this point or should I continue with or without the time and trait variables?

Comment: What correlation structure have you used?

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean this. My R Code for the predicted Model: lmer(Behaviour3 ~ poly(occasion_cs,2)*group+(1+occasion_cs| subject) + sex+age_cs+FFImeanN_cs+FFImeanE_cs+FFImeanO_cs+FFImeanC_cs+FFImeanA_cs,  data = data, REML = FALSE,  control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")). I started with a null model and then I entered the level 1 variable: lmer(Behaviour3~ poly(occasion_cs,2)+(1| subject),  data = data, REML = FALSE,control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")). After this I wanted to move on with the level 2 variables, but now I'm not sure if this would be right.

Comment: Converted to edit. What is the class of `occassion`? Factor or numeric?

Comment: Also, how did you land on this model specification? And what's your n?

Comment: N = 207 and occasion is numeric.

Comment: I land with this model specification due to my literature research. Besides the group variable (experimental and control group) the level 2 variables are related to my output variable (environmental behaviour) which is why I included them in the model.

Answer (score 0):

The correlation structure is determined by the random effect term `(1 + occassion_cs | subject)`. Each subject has a random intercept and a random slope in time. "Occassion" is an unusual term, more commonly we would use the term visit, timepoint, or wave depending on the study design. This is called an AR-1 autoregressive model. The idea is that observations within subjects are more correlated than observations between and that observations closer together in time are more correlated that observations farther apart in time.

However, you also adjust for the `occassion_cs` as a quadratic fixed effect. If "occassion" only has three levels as you say, you are probably running into collinearity of fixed and random effects. With so few time points, I don't think it makes sense to do this. Not an issue if your N is very large. But I gather it isn't, or that the variability in time is not quite as great as you have built your model to handle.

If I were faced with this analysis I would adjust for "growth" as a fixed effect (leave occassion_cs as a fixed effect and not a quadratic), and use an exchangeable correlation structure by *only* having the random intercept `(1|subject)`.

Comment: Thank you for this really understandable explanation!
But how would you proceed when this model (lmer(Behaviour3~ occasion_cs+(1| subject)) does not fit the data as well as the null model? Should I continue as planned with the model (lmer(Behaviour3 ~ occasion_cs*group+(1| subject) + sex+age_cs+ FFImeanN_cs+FFImeanE_cs+FFImeanO_cs+FFImeanC_cs+FFImeanA_cs) or does it not make sense to include the level two variables?

Comment: @clarmar I don't care about "fitting the model well". Behavioral/phenotypic data are *defined* by their high variance. If you don't know the model you want, you just risk overfitting and landing on invalid inference. Of course, including more terms (zodiac sign, left-footedness, and eye color) in a model yields better fit.